# Cannot replace child XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I am using XML as discuss forum in ASP.NET. I am trying to add functionality for updating comments. My XML structure is this:

```
<forum>
 <author id="1">
  <comment id="0" idUser="19">
   <name>....</name>
   <date>....</date>
   <message>...</message>
  </comment>
  <comment id="1" idUser="4">
   ....
  </comment>
 </author>
 <author id="2">
  ....
 </author>
</forum>
```

And my code is:

```
protected void btnEditComment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (messageTxb.Text!="" && nameTxb.Text!="")
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/forum.xml"));
        XmlNode newComment = (XmlNode)Session["Comment"];
        XmlNode oldComment = doc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//author[@id={0}]/comment[@id={1}]",Request.QueryString["id"],newComment.Attributes["id"].Value));
        newComment.ChildNodes[0].InnerText = nameTxb.Text.Trim();
        newComment.ChildNodes[1].InnerText = string.Format("{0:D}", DateTime.Now);
        newComment.ChildNodes[2].InnerText = messageTxb.Text.Trim();
        oldComment.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newComment, oldComment);
        doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/forum.xml"));
        Repeater1.DataBind();
        Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/user/Autor.aspx?id={0}", Request.QueryString["id"]));
    }
}
```

I get error

> 'The node to be inserted is from a different document context.'

It raises when I am trying to use the replaceChild method.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace this row:
oldComment.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(doc.ImportNode(newComment, true), oldComment);